# Returning last node in linked list recursively

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I'm trying to write function that returns the last node of a linked list recursively withour declaring any local variables. Is this right?

```
ListNode* lastPtr(ListNode* list){
If(list = NULL)
Return NULL;
Else 
List = lastPtr(list->next);
If(list->next = NULL)
Return list;
}
```

language is c++

Comment: `return (list && list->next) ? lastPtr(list->next) : list;` BTW: `If(list->next = NULL) ...` You probaby want `if(list->next == NULL) ...`

Comment: Are keywords case-insignificant in C++ ?

Comment: @wildplasser Not hardly. This has no chance of compiling as C++ past the second line (first if you include the fact that `ListNode` is not defined here either).

Comment: I realize I missed the ==.

Comment: This is not meant to compile its an exercise

Comment: Even If It Is An Exercise, You Should Stop Capitalising All Identifiers And Keywords!

Comment: im doing it in Microsoft word so It does it automatically not by me

Comment: You should considere using an IDE for writing programs ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
ListNode *lastPtr(ListNode* list) {
return (list && list->next) ? lastPtr(list->next) : list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the equal sign in C++ is, as in C, and Java is `==` and not `=`

Try to correct your code.

```
ListNode * lastNode(ListNode *list)
{
    if (list!=NULL)
    {
        if (list->next==NULL)
            return list;
        else return lastNode(list->next);
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```